# How to compare ArrayList elements

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, arraylist

```
private static ArrayList<Game> theWinnerIs(ArrayList<Game> gamer){
    ArrayList<Game> winner = new ArrayList<Game>();
    ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i<gamer.size(); i=i+1){
        int x = gamer.get(i).getPoints();
        winner.add(x);
    }

    return winner;
}
```

I have unknown amounts of elements in ArrayList gamer.
what i want to do is that, i want to loop trough every element in ArrayList gamer, and call a method on each on of them called getpoints();, to get their score. Then i want to compare the score on each one  of these elements, and store the element with the most score in the winner ArrayList, and then 
return winner.  if 2 or more elements share the most score, i want to store them in the winner Arraylist. hence the reason i use Arraylist, because i dont know how many winners.

i know i must use if statements to compare the elements. But i dont know how to start comparing them. how do i get each of their values and store it in 
if - statements. For simplicity lets say number of elements are 3. otherwise its unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Question is if you want a good performance or not. If not, then you can just sort that `ArrayList` using `sort` method and custom `Comparator` that's gonna be comparing the points, try this at the beggining of your method:

```
gamer.sort((p1, p2) -> p1.getPoints().compareTo(p2.getPoints()));
```

After this, gamers/players (I don't really understand your naming) with highest scores are gonna be at the end of the list, if there is only one highest score then he will be last. Then you just need to extract the last one from a list, and check the if previous one has the same score, if not then stop, if yes then add him too, and check previous to him etc.

Also, your `points` list is not necessary in your code, remember to remove it if you are not planing to do anything with it.